# How file will be handled when I'm writing something using ofstream object and piping output to same file?

Tags: c++, file, file-io, pipe, fstream

This is code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   ofstream out("file.txt");
   //cout<<"I'm being written on console and piped to file."<<endl;
   out<<"I'm directly being written on file using ofstream object"<<endl;
   cout<<"I'm being written on console and piped to file."<<endl;
}
```

On terminal, I'm writing:

```
./a.out > file.txt
```

In file, guess what I found?

```
I'm being written on console and piped to file.
m object
```

Please someone explain...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *If* you succeed in opening the same file twice, I'm not too surprised that both streams start writing from the beginning of the file. There is nothing in the C++ spec that says it should synchronize output with the shell.

Comment: What did you expect?